# AttributeError : 'str' object has no attribute 'cloud'

Tags: azure

When i use Azure CLI to deploy my PHP app by comment

---

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group gaoExtDBApp2Linux --name gaoExtDBApp2 --src clouddrive/sqltest.zip
```

---

It throws error

---

> 'str' object has no attribute 'cloud'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 194,
>   in invoke
>
> ```
> cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
> ```
>
> ....
>
> File
>   "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/client_factory.py",
>   line 83, in _get_mgmt_service_client
>
> ```
> resource = resource or cli_ctx.cloud.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cloud'

---

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is known issue:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/5335

and it had been fixed.

So let's wait for new release :(

Comment: Thank, now i don't know way to deploy my PHP app to azure :(

Comment: You could deploy with git https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git or ftp :)